# Nodejs doesn't start with docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to do a very basic thing with docker and node. I have a client with Nginx and a backend with nodejs.

My problem is that when I tried to run `docker-compose up -d` it gives me an `ok` but the backend is not running.

I think this is happening due to some problem with the "volumes", because if I get rid of this part in the docker-compose then it works. But I do want to have a volume to save and store all the backend related files.

This is my **docker-compose**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    nodeserver:
        container_name: nodebackend
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH}:/usr/src/app
        environment:
            TZ: 'Europe/Madrid'
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    nginx:
        container_name: client
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH}:/var/www/api
            - ${NGINX_APIX_LOGS}:/var/log/nginx/
        environment:
            TZ: 'Europe/Madrid'
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
```

And this is my Dockerfile (in the same directory)

```
# pull the Node.js Docker image
FROM node:12.15.0-alpine

# create the directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy the package.json files from local machine to the workdir in container
COPY package*.json ./

# run npm install in our local machine
RUN npm install --quiet
RUN npm install realm --quiet

# copy the generated modules and all other files to the container
COPY . /usr/src/app

# our app is running on port 5000 within the container, so need to expose it
EXPOSE 5000

# the command that starts our app
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

The directory tree is this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff     27 Dec 29 11:41 .dockerignore
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff    231 Dec 29 11:02 .env
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff    575 Dec 29 12:46 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  staff     96 Dec 29 12:03 api.files
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff    592 Dec 29 12:47 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  staff     96 Dec 29 11:02 logs
drwxr-xr-x  53 user  staff   1696 Dec 29 11:53 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff  31286 Dec 29 11:53 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff    338 Dec 29 11:53 package.json
```

The .env file is this one:

```
# Application's path (absolute or relative)
APP_PATH=/Users/user/Development/ContactListWebApp/api.files/

# Logs path
NGINX_APIX_LOGS=/Users/user/Development/ContactListWebApp/logs/nginx
```

If I run `docker-compose up -d` I get this message:

```
Starting client        ... done
Recreating nodebackend ... done
```

But if I run `docker ps -a`

This is what I have:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                  NAMES
d55463667a3d   contactlistwebapp_nodeserver   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 seconds ago   Exited (1) 23 seconds ago                          nodebackend
4b85504235a3   nginx:latest                   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   18 minutes ago   Up 23 seconds               0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   client
```

The **package.json** files have this information:

```
{
  "name": "contactlistwebapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test application to list contacts on web app linked to iOS app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Josman Pérez",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? If I **comment the volume part in the docker-compose then it runs**

Thank you

Comment: I'd consider deleting the `volumes:` to be a good solution: otherwise you're hiding everything the Dockerfile does, and you're really just running `node` in a particularly roundabout way.  What problems do you run into if you do that?

Comment: Really it doesn't have an impact, what I am doing is just for learning purposes. So, for example in my nginx all the files that the client uses are inside `api.files` and I wanted to do the same with the backend files... but it doesn't respond to a problem rather than just learning how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

#### First

In this command `CMD ["npm", "app.js"]`, it will not execute the node application.You should use `node` to run your application, such as `CMD ["node", "app.js"]`.

#### Second

In you docker-compose.yml, you use this volumes.

```
volumes:
    - ${APP_PATH}:/usr/src/app
```

Your `APP_PATH` is `APP_PATH=/Users/user/Development/ContactListWebApp/api.files/`. After Dockerfile is built and container start, your `/usr/src/app` will be mounted with your `${APP_PATH}` in `volumes config`. That means your other files and directories which are generated (COPY, RUN npm install) by your Dockerfile will disappear. You could change your CMD to this `CMD ["ls", "-al"]`, you'll find you only have `app.js`. There are no node_modules, package.json etc.

So, after you use `docker logs container_id` (closed container), you'll find your node couldn't find the express modules.

#### Solution

If you really want to use volumes config, you should not mount it to your WORKDIR (/usr/src/app), you should mount it to other path. When you want to use your volumes, you just find the files in that path, such as `/usr/src/app2`.

So, in your case, you could change the volumes path. If you don't need to use files in `${APP_PATH}`, you could just remove your volumes.

```
# this is just an example
volumes:
    - ${APP_PATH}:/usr/src/app2
```

Then change your CMD in Dockerfile with `CMD ["node", "api.files/app.js"]`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I just added the package.json file to the question, it doesn't have that its a pretty simple `npm init` command with only title and the `express` dependency

Comment: okay, I updated my answer. You could try it.

Comment: But, I'm curious where is your app.js? Why don't your directory tree contain it?

Comment: The `app.js` is inside the directory `api.files`. I have modified that to give it a try but the same result. The only thing that seems to work is if I comment on the `volume` part of the `docker-compose` for the nodebackend (and move out the `app.js` to the root directoy), then a `docker-compose up -d` followed by a `docker ps` gives me both containers up and running (both client and backend) but if I uncomment the volume part then after `docker-compose up -d` only the client is up...

Comment: where is your app.js? in `api.files`?

Comment: Yes. But if I comment on the volume part of the docker-compose file then I need to relocate the file to the root directory to be able to run it. But the thing here is that I want all my nodejs files inside api.files directory but with that and the volume on the docker-compose it doesn't run.

Comment: @neteot I updated my answer, you could try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226560/discussion-between-neteot-and-jack-yu).